# How do I call an elevated PowerShell from Windows command prompt to execute commands and a PowerShell script file?

Tags: powershell, cmd

The following script works fine in Powershell:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; Invoke-Webrequest
'https://blah.blob.core.windows.net/laps/AutoAutoPilot.ps1' -OutFile
C:\script.ps1; C:\script.ps1
```

I'm trying to convert it so that it runs as a CMD/BAT file. I simply need to double click to run it. I need the CMD/BAT file to run Powershell as administrator and from there, it will run the script from above. Here's what I have. It'll just quit straight away without doing anything.

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -c Start-Process -Verb RunAs -Wait
powershell.exe '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Noexit -c Set-Location
"\"\\\"%CD%\\\"\""; -c "& Invoke-Webrequest
\"https://blah.blob.core.windows.net/laps/AutoAutoPilot.ps1\"
-OutFile C:\script.ps1; C:\script.ps1" '
```

Update:

I got it working now. The full output looks like this:

```
powershell -Command "& ({Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -Command Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://blah.blob.core.windows.net/laps/AutoAutoPilot.ps1 -OutFile C:\script.ps1; C:\script.ps1'})"
```

Comment: What's with the third `-c`? I'm thinking about this part `;-c "& Invoke-Webrequest`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `-NoExit` parameter when starting `powershell.exe` PowerShell should not close after the script has finished running. Afterwards if you do not see errors, you can look at the `$error` variable, to see any errors which occurred when running your script.

You are trying to run your PowerShell code, using `PowerShell.exe` from command prompt, so you should be able to use the same code as you did before, when you were running your code directly in PowerShell before.

Comment: Of course -Noexit is supposed to not close Powershell. You're stating the obvious. Maybe try running the command yourself and you'll see why I made this post in the first place. The problem is how the commands are structured and how they are enclosed. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You can use PowerShell ISE run the code seeing as it's all PowerShell and then view the errors, if no output is given then look at the PowerShell $error variable

Comment: Running the command in ISE just closes ISE completely.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding you want to run powershell code in a batch-file.well Depending upon your preference there are multiple solutions to this problem(well i haven't checked any of them):

***Solution:1***

make a batch file and give your powershell script to it as a parameter.

Without Admin access:

```
@ECHO OFF
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%~dpn0.ps1'"
PAUSE
```

With Admin access:

```
@ECHO OFF
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dpn0.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
PAUSE
```

***Solution:2***

If you don't want an external .ps1 file,then you can try this.just save it as `something.bat`

```
powershell -command if ($true)^
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; Invoke-Webrequest 'https://blah.blob.core.windows.net/laps/AutoAutoPilot.ps1' -OutFile C:\script.ps1; C:\script.ps1^
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. I need admin access but how can I add "Invoke-Webrequest https://blah.blob.core.windows.net/laps/AutoAutoPilot.ps1
-OutFile C:\script.ps1; C:\script.ps1" to it?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
powershell -Command "& {Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -Command Set-Location -Path C:\whatever\working\directory\you\need; Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://blah.blob.core.windows.net/laps/AutoAutoPilot.ps1 -OutFile C:\script.ps1; C:\script.ps1'}"
```

---

**Explanation:**

When executing commands in PowerShell using the `-Command` argument, ExecutionPolicies do not apply as your are executing a single command and not a script. Even the execution of a scriptblock consisting of multiple commands counts as the execution of a single command. That's why you can directly call PowerShell from the command prompt like this (without anything else):

```
powershell -Command ...
```

`-Command` expects `-` to read from `stdin` or a scriptblock ([read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-command)). Scriptblocks have to be enclosed in curly braces (`{...}`). If you pass a scriptblock from the command prompt to PowerShell, you also have to add the [call operator `&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1#call-operator-):

```
powershell -Command "& {...}"
```

As you need an elevated PowerShell, you start a new PowerShell process from the previous PowerShell with `Start-Process` in combination with the `-Verb RunAs` argument. You add all arguments that you want to pass to the elevated PowerShell to the `-ArgumentList` argument:

```
... Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '...' ...
```

As you want to call a script file, you now need the corresponding ExecutionPolicy. If you don't want to change it on the system, you can bypass the ExecutionPolicy with `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` as you already did. And you also add `-NoExit` here. To pass your desired PowerShell commands, you use the `-Command` argument again. This time, you don't need the call operator and you can also omit the curly braces as we are now in PowerShell and not in the command prompt anymore.

```
... -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -Command Set-Location -Path C:\whatever\working\directory\you\need; Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://blah.blob.core.windows.net/laps/AutoAutoPilot.ps1 -OutFile C:\script.ps1; C:\script.ps1 ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still closes the window without executing anything.

Comment: If I do just this, it runs Powershell as admin just fine, but as soon as you add the "Invoke-WebRequest" bit into it, it closes the powershell window straight away.

powershell -Command "& {Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -Command Set-Location -Path C:\whatever\working\directory\you\need;'}"

Comment: Can you confirm that this works? `powershell -Command "& {Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -Command Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.google.com -OutFile C:\script.ps1; Get-Date'}"` It should download the google website to `C:\script.ps1` and display the current date afterwards while PowerShell stays open.